# Assign Arraylist to residemenu item

Tags: android, residemenu

I am creating an residemenu with dynamic contents. I am receiving Residemenu items from service. Now I want to assign that arraylist as Residemenu main items like Home, New Order etc...
I have this arralist

```
 ArrayList<String> MenuHeadersAL = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and trying to assign like

```
for(int i=0; i<MenuHeadersAL.size();i++){
        ResideMenuItem MenuItem = new ResideMenuItem(this,R.drawable.ic_veg,MenuHeadersAL.get(i));
        resideMenu.addMenuItem(MenuItem, ResideMenu.DIRECTION_LEFT);
    }
```

I have 10 values in arraylist but not getting anything in reside menu. Residemenu is blank.

For This I am not using any adapter.
When I use

```
 itemHome = new ResideMenuItem(this, R.drawable.ic_veg, "Home");
 itemNewOrder = new ResideMenuItem(this, R.drawable.ic_veg, "New Order");
```

and

```
 resideMenu.addMenuItem(itemHome, ResideMenu.DIRECTION_LEFT);
 resideMenu.addMenuItem(itemNewOrder, ResideMenu.DIRECTION_LEFT);
```

Then I am able to see menu option but when I am assigning it dynamically then Reside menu is blank.

Comment: Post your code here..than we able to help you

Comment: Thanks friends for -ve mark. But can you tell me right way ?

Comment: +1..For your editing..Whenever we ask  question here than we have to give full information of the question..can u plz tell me where is your adapter...which you are going to set..Provide more information here...Here SO, there is not enmity of any one..Question or answer which is seems to have some effort than they get the up-vote or down-vote

Comment: Again , i am saying that, provide full information here, plz edit your question again...

Answer (score 0):

Done !!! Actually I was assigning arraylist to menuitem just after calling service. So there is service thread executes quite late and menulist item line executes with null arraylist. Thanks....